# Springs Rowmapper throwing type mismatch issue.

Tags: java, spring, frameworks

I have a domain object containing a variable, as a list of values from netezza and 4 more variables which are normal variables which will get assigned values from oracle db using row mapper.

The statement below is throwing error saying : Type mismatch: cannot convert from List to CharacteristicsValue. Is it because the domain object contains a list as a variable inside.

> CharacteristicsValue charValue = jdbcOMTemplate.query(builtQuery, new
>   DimCharRowMapper());

I can make the variable as List which will solve the issue but wanted to know whether there is any better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`query()` method returns a `List` of values.

`queryForObject()` method returns a single `Object`.

If you search a single object replace `query` with `queryForObject`.

If you need a list change the type of variable `charValue` to `List<CharacteristicsValue>`

**Note:** `queryForObject()`throw an `IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException` if the result of the query is not exactly one record. `query()` instead is working well also to retrieve zero, one or more records.

Comment: Thanks. So that object will in turn return me all the columns from result set.Won't it ?

Comment: Yes if in the DimCharRowMapper you mapped all columns. Note that if the record doesn't exists an exception is thrown (is not returned null as in similar methods of ORM frameworks).

Comment: If you think that this answer is correct you can flag it with the green flag. Thanks